# python mypy errors datetime v object and itemgetter v lambda

Tags: python, mypy

Why am I getting mypy errors on the following code:

```
import os
from operator import itemgetter
from datetime import datetime

def get_data() -> list[dict[str, str | datetime]]:

    x = []
    for fname in os.listdir():
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(fname))
        x.append({"fname": fname, "dt": dt})
    x = sorted(x, key=itemgetter("dt"))
    y = sorted(x, key=lambda i: i['dt']) # line 12
    return x #line 13
```

Errors:

```
x.py:12: error: Argument "key" to "sorted" has incompatible type "Callable[[Dict[str, object]], object]"; expected "Callable[[Dict[str, object]], Union[SupportsDunderLT, SupportsDunderGT]]"
x.py:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "object", expected "Union[SupportsDunderLT, SupportsDunderGT]")
x.py:13: error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[Dict[str, object]]", expected "List[Dict[str, Union[str, datetime]]]")
```

Using `itemgetter` has the same effect as `lambda` for sorting, but are treated differently by mypy

`x` appears to be a str or datetime

Comment: The error is the `dict` objects you are mapping have both strings and `datetime` objects as values, but your return type says the dicts in the list *only* have `datetime` objects as values.

Comment: More concretely, `{"fname": "foo.txt", "dt": datetime(2022, 7, 13)}` (or similar) does *not* have type `dict[str,datetime]`. `TypedDict('...', fname=str, dt=datetime)` would capture the type of `dict` you are constructing.

Comment: `dict[x, y]` is the type of dict with keys of type `x` and values of type `y`, not values of type `x` and type `y`.

Comment: Oops, I meant to write `dict[str, str | datetime]`.

Comment: Hm, if you get rid of line 11 (the first sort), what happens? I wonder if the used of `sorted` is "widening" the type of `x` in a way that prevents using it a second time.

Comment: Without first sort
```
x.py:12: error: Argument "key" to "sorted" has incompatible type "Callable[[Dict[str, object]], object]"; expected "Callable[[Dict[str, object]], Union[SupportsDunderLT, SupportsDunderGT]]"
x.py:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "object", expected "Union[SupportsDunderLT, SupportsDunderGT]")
x.py:13: error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[Dict[str, object]]", expected "List[Dict[str, Union[str, datetime]]]")
```

Comment: Without second sort ```x.py:13: error: Incompatible return value type (got "List[Dict[str, object]]", expected "List[Dict[str, Union[str, datetime]]]")```